# Viewing all documents on IBM Cloudant through API

Tags: cloudant

I'm trying an API that will list all values within all documents in my Cloudant database. I use '_all_docs' at the end of my API however this only shows the IDs and revs of my JSON documents, it does not show all values within the documents. Can an API show all the data within the documents, or should I be creating a 1 document with arrays (representing what would be rows on an SQL table)?

Comment: You need to pass the parameter `?include_docs=true` to return the document content.

Comment: That works cheers Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the contents of the document append the following to the query string.

`include_docs=true`

You can also use this on Views and Search indexes to get the complete doc.